# Using amcharts and getting javascript error

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using amcharts for a little app for personal use.  I got a static local copy working the way i wanted, but when I made some changes to make it dynamic I am not getting

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'time' of undefined or null reference
```

At serial.js line 46, position 364.

The code:

```js
  // SERIAL CHART
  chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();

  chart.dataProvider = chartData;
  chart.categoryField = "date";
  chart.balloon.bulletSize = 5;

  // listen for "dataUpdated" event (fired when chart is inited) and call zoomChart method when it happens
  chart.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);

  // AXES
  // category
  var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
  categoryAxis.parseDates = true; // as our data is date-based, we set parseDates to true
  categoryAxis.minPeriod = "DD"; // our data is daily, so we set minPeriod to DD
  categoryAxis.minorGridEnabled = true;
  categoryAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";
  categoryAxis.twoLineMode = true;
  categoryAxis.dateFormats = [{
                    period: 'fff',
                    format: 'JJ:NN:SS'
                }, {
                    period: 'ss',
                    format: 'JJ:NN:SS'
                }, {
                    period: 'mm',
                    format: 'JJ:NN'
                }, {
                    period: 'hh',
                    format: 'JJ:NN'
                }, {
                    period: 'DD',
                    format: 'DD'
                }, {
                    period: 'WW',
                    format: 'DD'
                }, {
                    period: 'MM',
                    format: 'MMM'
                }, {
                    period: 'YYYY',
                    format: 'YYYY'
  }];

  // first value axis (on the left)
  var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
  valueAxis.axisColor = "#FF6600";
  valueAxis.axisThickness = 2;
  chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

  // GRAPHS (one per line you want to make which for us is one line per user
  var users = listUsers();
  var bulletList=["round", "square", "triangleUp", "triangleDown", "triangleLeft", "triangleRight", "bubble", "diamond"];
  var colorList=["#00FF00", "#FF0000", "#0000FF", "#FF00FF", "#FFFF00", "#00FFFF", "#000000"];
  var bulletIndex = 0;
  var colorIndex = 0;
  for(var user in users) {
    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.valueAxis = valueAxis; // we have to indicate which value axis should be used
    graph.title = users[user];
    graph.valueField = users[user];
    graph.bullet = bulletList[bulletIndex++];
    graph.hideBulletsCount = 30;
    graph.bulletBorderThickness = 1;
    graph.lineColor = colorList[colorIndex++];
    chart.addGraph(graph);

    if(bulletIndex >= bulletList.length) {
      bulletIndex = 0;
    }
    if(colorIndex >= colorList.length) {
      colorIndex = 0;
    }
  }

  // CURSOR
  var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
  chartCursor.cursorAlpha = 0.1;
  chartCursor.fullWidth = true;
  chartCursor.valueLineBalloonEnabled = true;
  chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

  // SCROLLBAR
  var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
  chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

  // LEGEND
  var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
  legend.marginLeft = 110;
  legend.useGraphSettings = true;
  chart.addLegend(legend);

  // WRITE
  chart.write("chartdiv");
```

The sample data:

```
var allData = {
  "series1" : [ {
    "date" : new Date("01/05/2017"),
    "Brian" : 290,
    "Lisa" : 188
  }, {
    "date" : new Date("01/06/2017"),
    "Brian" : 289,
    "Lisa" : 188
  }, {
    "date" : new Date("01/07/2017"),
    "Brian" : 288,
    "Lisa" : 187
  } ],
  "series2" : [ {
    "date" : new Date("01/05/2017"),
    "Brian" : 28.9,
    "Lisa" : 18.8
  }, {
    "date" : new Date("01/06/2017"),
    "Brian" : 28.9,
    "Lisa" : 18.8
  }, {
    "date" : new Date("01/07/2017"),
    "Brian" : 28.8,
    "Lisa" : 18.7
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your data format, it's not the expected format for the `dataProvider`. The `dataProvider` is an array of objects, as you can see from [the demos on AmCharts' site](https://www.amcharts.com/demos). You have an object containing two arrays of objects in series1 and series2, which won't work. This is how the data should look:

```
[{
  "date": <your string date, millisecond timestamp, or date object>,
  "Brian": <value>,
  "Lisa": <value>
}, 
// ... etc
]
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ubLcudcn/)

If the multiple series are meant to be compared within the same chart, then you should look into [how to create a stock chart](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/your-first-stock-chart/), which appears to be more in line with what you're trying to do. The "series1" and "series2" arrays can be expressed as `DataSet` objects.

Here's a [quick and dirty fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ehy006L/2/) that implements your data into a stock chart, leveraging most of your code to get you started.